# Does Lord Shiva have any Mace (Gada)? Did Lord Shiva ever fight with mace?

Tags: scripture, shiva, vishnu, shaivism, shiva-purana

As we know that Narayana has a mace named Kaumadi.. in the same way, does Lord Shiva also have a mace? Does Lord Shiva know mace fighting?

Comment: *Does Lord Shiva know mace fighting?* This is silly to ask because Śiva is himself from whom the vidyā of Dhanurveda has come to us, and he is Īśvara. There is no śastra which he can't use and no matter which weapon he uses, no one can compare to his skill.

Comment: @Bingming Shiva isn't Ishvara, Shiva is Deva. Ishwara word is used for Narayana only